# Reproduce ActiveJob::DeserializationError on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I need for testing purpose to reproduce an ActiveJob::DeserializationError on rails console, I need to test the behaviour manually on testing environment.

```
class WrapperJob < ApplicationJob
  discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError

  def perform(event)
    # doing something
  end
end
```

The `WrapperJob` aims to perform something on the event, but during the enqueue time it might happen to remove event from database. I need a way please to reproduce `ActiveJob::DeserializationError`. right now I tried to pass a missing event, or a missing GlobalID but actually fail on the `# doing something` part instead of raising `DeserializationError`.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your `queue_apdater`? I'm not sure if it tries to serialize/deserialize if your `queue_adapter` is inline or `async`.

Comment: It's a `DelayedJob` async adapter, If got you right.

Comment: Okay, I don't think the async adapter actually deserializes anything, since it's not connected to an actual queuing mechanism.